# Trouble with SQL query from VBA when trying to select fields of 'Widestring' type (Access .mbd file)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, widestring

I am trying to import some data from a .mbd-file into Excel.
I can copy the whole database into a spreadsheet, no problem there.
I can also use a statement like this

```
sSQL = "SELECT HOEHE " & "FROM h_datei WHERE HOEHE >= 53 "
```

The problem arises when using WHERE on a field that has type other than int or float. (I don't have MS Access, but MDB Plus tells me the type for text fields in my .mdb is called 'Widestring')

I get this in a MsgBox from Excel:
Run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)':
Automation error

I have been googling and tinkering for quite a while, but I am stuck. Under is my VBA code. 
I don't know if this has to do with the provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) but I have tried a few others. 
I'm also thinking about unicode, as this database is from a german surveying program.

```
sConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & _
            sPath & "Oskarb04.mdb"

sSQL = "SELECT HOEHE " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR >= 53 "
Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
Debug.Print sSQL
rsData.Open sSQL, sConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnknown
```

Comment: If it is a string then you wouldn't use >= (unless implicit conversions supported and applicable). Do you mean  Where x 'Like' ? Or even '=' ? What are some of the example items in this field?

Comment: I could select some of the fields containing strings now, i had forgotten quotes! But one problem persists: 
PNR is a column in the database that contains only integers (at least in this case) but the type is 'WideString'. 
I know theres a value 1169.
`'SELECT hoehe FROM h_datei WHERE PNR = '1169'`
returns nothing and
`SELECT hoehe FROM h_datei WHERE PNR = 1169`
gives me the automation error

Comment: `sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR <= '1169' "`
(with the smaller than sign) gives me the whole column

Comment: try with an N before for unicode string

Comment: `sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR = '309' "`
No results.

`sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR = 309 "`
Automation error

`sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR LIKE '309' "`
No results.

Column PNR is type widestring and contains the value 309

Comment: sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR = N'309'"  ? I don't know if N needed before pnr.

Comment: `sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr " & "FROM h_datei WHERE PNR = N'309' "`

Gives me automation error

Comment: Try some sort of cast on the column ? sSQL = "SELECT hoehe, pnr" & "FROM h_datei WHERE StrConv(PNR,128) = '309'  ? see here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/strconv-function-19c3816f-dbc9-4adf-891c-fd32734c92e0

Comment: Also, worth keeping pnr as pnr in both cases not PNR but that is cosmetic.

Comment: I tried the casting you described, but it still doesn't give me any data.

Comment: I know converted the field type to number in MS Access, and it works. But it's not a good workaround, i need it to be seamless from excel, and besides the column wil hold strings sometimes. I can not find out what i'm doing wrong.

MS Acces says this about the fields:
IME-mode : No control
IME-sentencemode : no conversion
Textformat : Plain text

This is translated from norwegian

Comment: Aha!
Leading spaces in the strings!
sSQL = "SELECT pnr, hoehe " & "FROM h_datei " & _
            "WHERE pnr = '        100001'"

This works, but it's different lenghts on the strings. 
LTRIM(pnr) worked!

Comment: post as answer so others will be able to see :-)

Answer (score 0):

For string comparisons you would normally use the ['Like'](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator e.g.

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;
```

You can combine this with Wildcards to get partial matches. An example from that link:

[image: Wildcards]

For an exact match you can use `"="`

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN = 'myString';
```

If something like `">="` works on a string field then I suspect that field has been incorrectly set, I am guessing as unfamiliar with the software in question,and/or, an implicit conversion is able to be performed which incurs performance overhead and is susceptible to breaking.

If it is a unicode string, which a quick Google seems to imply a `widestring` datatype is, then

```
WHERE columnN = N'myString'
```

Failing that you can always try casting the column to a different type e.g.

```
StrConv(PNR,128) = '309'
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow